# Can not access other users' data using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

1. This is my app's api permissions

[api permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAumU.png)

2. This is my postman settings
   [postman settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYTe3.png)
3. I can get token successfully using an AD admin account
4. I can get all users successfully

[user list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXFUX.png)

5. I can create calendar event successfully using this AD admin' user id
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDIly.png)
6. I can not create calendar event using another user id
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D57T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is the document api for introducing the [api permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), you can see **Permission type** with `Delegated` and `Application`.

The second, this is the section for introducing the [request example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request), you can see that there are 2 types `/me` and `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}`.

The difference between the 2 kinds of api permission is that, using `Delegated` permission means we need to make users sign in first to generate the access token and call the api, while `Application` permission not. So when we use `Delegated` api permission, we can use api request like `/me` because the token contained the user information so graph api knows who is `me` and `me` is authorized to access this api. So we can also use `users/user_principle_name_of_the_signed_in_user` here. But it doesn't mean we can use another user principle name here, because other users aren't authorized in the access token.

How can we put any user of your tenant into the request and call the api successfully? We need to use `Application` permission here. When you add api permission, you may notice it and please add application api permission. Then we need to use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret) to generate access token with application permission. Then you may try yor failed request with the new token.

[image]

Application permission means you are calling the graph api on behalf the application, so it doesn't require users to sign in, but using delegated permission is much more safe since it will generate access token with limited scope(the api permission you defined in the token generating request), but client credential flow uses `/.defalut` as the scope, this means all the application api permission in the azure ad application will be added to the generated token, you can't control which application permission is allowed and which is not allowed in one token.